# Permission is not being set to the SVN repository users

Tags: linux, svn

I have just setup the SVN server in my local network. For that i followed this [link](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Subversion). But my problem is whatever user i have created in my `/etc/svn-auth-conf` file are only allowed to do checkout and commit,in fact this user have all rights. How do i restrict their permissions?

Here is my `/etc/httpd/conf.d/subversion.conf` file

```
LoadModule dav_svn_module     modules/mod_dav_svn.so
LoadModule authz_svn_module   modules/mod_authz_svn.so

<Location /repos>
   DAV svn
   SVNParentPath /var/www/html/svn
   AuthType Basic
   AuthName "Subversion repos"
   AuthUserFile /etc/svn-auth-conf
   Require valid-user
</Location>
```

And the other thing is, when i am creating any repository using `svnadmin` command then diffrent configuration file is been created in repositories `conf` folder like `authz,passwd,svnserve.conf`. I followed [this link](http://wiki.wsmoak.net/cgi-bin/wiki.pl?Subversion/Configuration) for setting permissions.

So how do i set the specific permission to specific users ?

i.e

```
user1=All permissions
user2=read
other=none
```

Comment: Please don't post your question on multiple sites: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56272/permission-is-not-being-set-to-the-svn-repository-users

Comment: The unix site question is gone. This question should be the one to stay open

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For access via http, you have to include permisions on a per-folder basis in your authz file

like this:

```
[/]
#rw is read-write, r is read only, and empty is none
user1 = rw
user2 = r
* =
```

You can also define groups of users in the [groups] section, and assign permissions using the @group_name like this:

```
[groups]
dev = jdoe,user3
qa = user4,user5

[/some/other/path]
@dev = rw
@qa = r
* =
```

**Edit**
Finally, your apache conf is missing a vital part, it have to include the AuthzSVNAccessFile directive, something like:

```
    <Location /project/src>
            DAV svn
            SVNPath /var/svn/project
            AuthzSVNAccessFile /var/svn/project/conf/authz
            AuthType Basic
            AuthName "Project source repository"
            AuthUserFile /var/svn/.dav_svn.passwd
            Require valid-user
    </Location>
```

Comment: i have added this in `authz` [file](http://pastie.org/5410366) and i just checked out on different server. when i tried to edit the file and committed then its just prompt me for user name and password and committed successfully. This is user was not defined in `authz` file.

Comment: I believe you should update apache's conf to tell SVN module to use this file.  Take a look in the SVN official manual.  It is described in detail what you need to do.

Comment: Thaks @AdrianShum can you provide me proper link for that ? i restarted the apache server 2-3 times

Comment: i have one last question, here i should create `<Location></Location>` directive for my each separate repository right ? here  this is for project repository. make me clear if i am wrong

Comment: you create one <location> for each (physical) svn repository. If you store one project per repository or multiple projects per repository is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 chown -R groupname:groupname folder
 chmod -R <permission> directory-name/
```

permission can be 766 for user to read write and execute and for others and group to read and write

Check the man pages for more information

to set the user and read or write restrictions

Comment: can you give me some example to do this ? i haven't given all the permission to this repositories.

Comment: I have made changes please check and let me know

Comment: @juned are you using http to access the repositories or are you doing it by other means?

Comment: @jachguate i am using http to access repositories. it always authenticates the user which are in `/etc/svn-auth-conf` file

Comment: Thanks @jachguate my problem is solved, thanks to point me to a right direction :)